# why isn't my dialog box responding to OnRButtonDown(), in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to make one of my dialog boxes respond when right clicked on.
I tried using a break point to see when the user clicks the dialog with a right mouse button, but it doesn't respond.

I thought the codes below were all I needed to receive the information from windows, but i don't know what is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

my .h file:

```
afx_msg void OnRButtonDown(UINT, CPoint);
```

my cpp file:

```
void CGadgetAddedDialog::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// THIS METHOD ISN'T RESPONDING TO MY Right Mouse Button

    CDialogEx::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGadgetAddedDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Check if you have an invisible control which captures the click.

Comment: Yes, you were right. My invisible control was detecting the hits and not my dialog.